# Converting varbinary to image

Tags: c#, silverlight

I managed to convert an Image to a varbinary and store it in my database. I have been trying to convert the varbinary to an Image but I'm running in some trouble here.

First I get the Binary from my database in my service.

```
    public Binary getAfbeelding(int id)
    {

        var query = (from p in dc.Afbeeldings
                     where p.id == id
                     select p.source).Single();

        Binary source = query;
        return source;
    }
```

Then I try to convert the varbinary to an image, using code found on StackOverflow:

```
    public static string convertToImage(Binary source)
    {
        byte[] b = source.ToArray();
        MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(b);
        Image img = Image.FromStream(ms);
        return img.Source.ToString();
    }
```

I am running into trouble before the call to `new MemoryStream` :

> 'OndernemersAward.EditAfbeeldingServiceReference.Binary' does not contain a definition for 'ToArray' and no extension method 'ToArray' accepting a first argument of type
>       'OndernemersAward.EditAfbeeldingServiceReference.Binary' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

For some weird reason, I CANNOT use the 'normal' Binary, it will ALWAYS tell me to use `OndernemersAward.EditAfbeeldingServiceReference.Binary` which is my ServiceReference, as you can see.

How can this be solved?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

1) Add reference into your project to System.Data.Linq.dll

2) And then try this:

```
public static Image ConvertToImage(System.Data.Linq.Binary iBinary)
    {
        var arrayBinary = iBinary.ToArray();
        Image rImage = null;

        using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(arrayBinary))
        {
            rImage = Image.FromStream(ms);
        }
        return rImage;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

What's happening here is that the compiler thinks that `Binary` is a class in your namespace `OndernemersAward.EditAfbeeldingServiceReference`.

Your code in `convertToImage` expects that the parameter named `source` is of type [`System.Data.Linq.Binary`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.linq.binary.aspx). The code you found on StackOverflow assumed that was the data type.

If you have a class in your own namespace, rename it to something else to avoid this naming duplicate. IF that's not a good option, then consider being explicit in your code to use the fully qualified namespace when using the 2 `Binary` classes.

Comment: The weird thing is that I don't have a class called Binary. 
I managed to fix by converting the Binary to a byte[] inside my service.             `byte[] source = query.ToArray();
            return source;`
But now when trying to convert the Image, it seems that in silverlight, images don't have the `.FromStream`. (I also cannot use `System.Drawing`)

Answer (score 0):

Probably you created Binary class in OndernemersAward.EditAfbeeldingServiceReference namespace.

Add

> System.Data.Linq.dll

library to your references. Then write:

```
using System.Data.Linq;
....

public static Image ConvertToImage(Binary iBinary)
        {
            var arrayBinary = iBinary.ToArray();
            Image rImage = null;

            using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(arrayBinary))
            {
                rImage = Image.FromStream(ms);
            }
            return rImage;
        }
```

Comment: I tried referencing to `System.Data.Linq` but I can't seem to do that in my xaml.cs file.
`The type or namespace name 'Data' does not exist in the namespace 'System'`