# How do I convert a VarBinary Value to an image?

Tags: c#, image, memorystream, varbinary

I have a Table in my database like so:

```
Id  |  Description  | Icon
```

where the `Icon` column is of type `varbinary(max)`

I have a row in this table where the value in the `Icon` column is shown in the pastebin link (because it is a long value):

http://pastebin.com/LbVAf20A

I am trying to convert this varbinary value to an Image in my program using the following code mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8280457/2987066):

```
var binary = new System.Data.Linq.Binary(GetBytes(StreamText)).ToArray();
using (MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream(binary))
{
    var image = new System.Drawing.Bitmap(stream);
    image.Save(DownloadPath, ImageFormat.Png);
}

private byte[] GetBytes(string str)
{
    byte[] bytes = new byte[str.Length * sizeof(char)];
    System.Buffer.BlockCopy(str.ToCharArray(), 0, bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
        return bytes;
}
```

Where `StreamText` is the string in the pastebin link

But at the row `var image...` I keep getting the exception.

> Parameter is not valid

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Why do you get your varbinary column as string from database, and not as byte array directly?

Comment: @Evk for convenience I am copying and pasting the `string` value of my varbinary column and want to just convert that to an image. If i got the value directly I would need alot more UI to let the user choose a table, and row

Comment: @user1 Copy and pasting from what?

Comment: @Juharr logging onto Sqlserver, viewing the table using `Select * from table` and copying and pasting the valye of the `Icon` column

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem is your string is hex string, and you trying to convert it to byte array as if it was ascii string. You can use any method you can find around internet to convert your hex string to byte array, like this:

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var s = "your long hex string";
        if (s.StartsWith("0x"))
            s = s.Remove(0, 2);
        using (var stream = new MemoryStream(ConvertHexStringToByteArray(s)))
        {
            var image = new Bitmap(stream);
            image.Save(DownloadPath, ImageFormat.Png);
        }            
    }

    public static byte[] ConvertHexStringToByteArray(string hexString) {
        if (hexString.Length%2 != 0) {
            throw new ArgumentException(String.Format(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, "The binary key cannot have an odd number of digits: {0}", hexString));
        }

        byte[] HexAsBytes = new byte[hexString.Length/2];
        for (int index = 0; index < HexAsBytes.Length; index++) {
            string byteValue = hexString.Substring(index*2, 2);
            HexAsBytes[index] = byte.Parse(byteValue, NumberStyles.HexNumber, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
        }

        return HexAsBytes;
    }
```